# How can I change the color of search box input icon?

Tags: search, color-swatches, input

It's defined like this "@icon-search: '\e615';". I just want to change into  green.[image]

Comment: can you share your website url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the below **css code** in to  your custom theme.

```
.block-search .action.search::before {
     color: green !important;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be easier if your changing all header icons

You can just set this variable in your local child theme
@header-icons-color:green;